# FireMonkey: 2 Form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I had a question. I created 2 forms, first appears at the beginning, but after a while I need to finally destroy it and switch to the second, switching works, but if you press the back button (on the phone), a black screen appears, because it goes to the first form that I destroy, poidee and must close the application. How to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OnKeyUp event of the second form to detect pressing the back button:

```
if Key = vkHardwareBack then
begin
  // if you want, close the app.
  Key := 0;
end
```

if you want to close the app:

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
MainActivity.finish; 
{$ENDIF}
```